# Почему в VS не видит js?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

я скачала макет сайта в котором есть подсписок с стрелочкой(при нажатии поворачивается вверх и вниз соответственно)
при воспроизведении макета все ок

но я перенесла его в свой проект asp.net. в файле css вот эта строчка подчеркивается

```css
 -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
```

Студия пишет что этот фрагмент не является известным для css.

сами js файлы в идее видит: я их отключала и открытие подсписка переставало работать

что ему не хватает? мб nuget какой нужен?

Изменено: желтым выделен файл где я нахожусь
синим подчеркнула файл исчезновение которого влечет за собой исчезновение стрелочки. получается что он есть у меня в проекте, но VS его не видит. может что-то с путем не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: по итогу вместо стрелочки квадратик.

Comment: Тот код, что вы предоставили, стрелочкой не является, это стиль для плавной смены цвета какого-то элемента. То, что у вас стрелочка квадратиком, скорее всего говорит о том, что у вас проблема с подключением иконочных шрифтов.

Comment: я дополнила вопрос. нашла какой файл/ vs не видит но не понимаю почемy

Comment: Укажите полный а не относительный путь.

Comment: полный путь не помогает

Comment: добавьте в вопрос кусок содержания .css в виде текста, а не в виде обрезанного скриншота, пожалуйста. Там указано несколько файлов шрифтов, из скриншота не видно сколько и каких.

Comment: проблема решилась сама собой когда я перекопировала файлы в новый проект. наверное что-то было упущено в прошлый раз, правда так и не поняла что

Comment: если хотите разобраться и умеете или готовы научиться, то сделайте два коммита (вариант проекта с ошибкой и работающий вариант) и выведите разницу (`diff`) между коммитами. В дальнейшем в работе это один из необходимых навыков для выявления и документации багов.